# Different console window for different threads

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, fork, windows-console

I want to create two different console windows for two different threads running in a single process. I know that only one console window is allocated per process. So even though I create multiple threads, all the threads use the same console window as STDOUT. What should I do now? Do I need to create two different processes for two different functions? If so how can I access the memory on one process from another?

Comment: check this: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/111631-one-process-two-console-windows.html

Comment: Why do you need more than one console? Imagine that you require more than one keyboard, mouse and monitor. What purpose would that do?

Comment: @Dialecticus Suppose I have multiple worker threads that each have their own list of tasks to perform. And suppose it is known that multiple worker threads will (at some point) block, waiting for user input (`stdin`). Let's say that at all time, the user wants to see the progress of each thread (e.g., the "task" that it's working on) and to provide it input if the thread task requires. Having a separate monitor, keyboard, and mouse (i.e., console) to allow the user to independently interface with each thread would satisfy user requirements.

Comment: According to the OP, `all the threads use the same console window as stdout`. This is problematic if we were to use one console window (as I've encountered, in my own toy program) because multiple worker threads may write to the console at the same time, interleaving their outputs. If a thread reads from `stdin` and the user input is echoed out to the console screen, you will see this on the console screen too. So if it isn't possible to spawn multiple consoles, one for each thread, within a multi-threaded process, is *multiprocess* the appropriate thing to use?

Comment: @MinhTran there is only one stdin and only one stdout. It is not possible to have more than one. If you need a way to feed data to your threads, or get data from them, then you have to use something else instead of stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AllocConsole function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states "*A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console.*"; a process can ony be attached to a single console.
Your desire can only be accomplished by multiple processes. The inter-process communication for such a purpose can be best implemented by using [pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (See "[How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351/EN-US)" as a starter). This way you may open a number of processes, each of which with a console, and "pipe" the I/O from/to them.